# Visual studio 2010 floating windows on top behaviour

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So i'm using Visual Studio 2010 with a dual monitor setup and I like to have my Build/Team -explorer tab on my other screen.

But the the problem I am raging with is the following:

"sketch" of the problem: http://pastebin.com/X8K3ihGJ

If i'm coding and I switch to the word doc on screen 1 (it pops to the front (y) )
But if i then want to click on the build explorer on screen 2, the vs main screen on screen 1 goes to the front.

Is there anyway it's possible you can set the visual studio windows' on top state's independent from each other?

It's a minor issue but it's hurting me all day :)

Thx!

Comment: This is not an option, focusing a VS window brings all of them to the foreground.  Unpleasant, but the alternative is much worse.  If it wouldn't work this way then an undocked window would get lost behind another window with no decent way to get it back without adding a gazillion taskbar buttons.  Multiple monitors is a core developer productivity enhancer for very little money.

Answer (score 4):

Try the Productivity Power Tools extension.  Dock the build explorer in a floating tab well and enable the "enable independent floating tab well" option in the Document Tab Well settings.  This will allow windows to be on top independent of each other.

Comment: Those floating windows being set on top when the main window of VS2010 was brought to focus really annoyed me. I'm very happy with this extension.